# Querying a agregate count in GraphQL

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js, graphql

i have a n:m association between User and Movie

```
const UserMovie = db.define('user_movie', {
  state: {
  type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
  allowNull: false,
  },
});    

User.belongsToMany(Movie, { through: UserMovie });
Movie.belongsToMany(User, { through: UserMovie });
```

i would like to query the UserMovie an get the count of user group by movie where state is "true". so i wrote :

```
user_movie: {
    type: new GraphQLList(UserMovie),
    args: {
      offset: {
        type: GraphQLInt
      },
      limit: {
        type: GraphQLInt
      },
      users: {
        type: new GraphQLList(GraphQLInt)
      }
    },
    resolve (root, args) {
      return db.models.user_movie.findAll({
        offset: args.offset,
        limit: args.limit,
        where: {
          state: true,
          userId: [args.users]
        },
        attributes: ['movieId', [sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('userId')), 'usercount']],
        group: 'movieId',
      });
    }
  },
```

But every time i query it, it's returning a usercount null

Thanks for your help.

Comment: let's continue here. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130066/querying-a-agregate-count-in-graphql

Comment: moreover it's asking the good SQL Query : `SELECT state, createdAt, updatedAt, userId, movieId, COUNT(userId) AS usercount FROM user_movies AS user_movie WHERE user_movie.state = true AND user_movie.userId IN (1) GROUP BY movieId;`